# Using dplyr: Within groups, select the first value meeting a condition

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I need assistance obtaining a solution that will scan backwards in time and obtain the first value meeting a condition. I have data similar to:

```
set.seed(42)

df <- data.frame(
  id = sample(LETTERS[1:3], 20, replace = TRUE),
  time.var = sample(1:20, 20, replace = TRUE),
  x = sample(c(1:10), 20, replace = TRUE)
  )

df <- df[order(df$id, df$time.var),]

 id time.var  x
  A        5  2
  A       14  8
  A       19  7
  A       20  1
  B        1  1
  B        2  5
  B        9 10
  B       11 10
  B       13  6
  B       15  4
  B       19  3
  C        1  7
  C        3  5
  C        8  9
  C        8  4
  C       17  7
  C       17  4
  C       17  8
  C       19  4
  C       19 10
```

For the last member of each group defined in time order by `time.var`, I'd like to obtain the first value from `x` less than 5 by scanning in descending time order.

I have tried:

```
test <- df %>% 
        group_by(id) %>% 
        arrange(id, time.var) %>% 
        mutate(less.5 = which.max(x[x < 5]) )
```

What strategy can I use to obtain this type of output:

```
 id time.var  x  previous.less.5
  A        5  2
  A       14  8
  A       19  7
  A       20  1      2
  B        1  1
  B        2  5
  B        9 10
  B       11 10
  B       13  6
  B       15  4
  B       19  3      4
  C        1  7
  C        3  5
  C        8  9
  C        8  4
  C       17  7
  C       17  4
  C       17  8
  C       19  4
  C       19 10      4
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Using `library(dplyr)`:*

```r
df %>% 
  arrange(id, time.var) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(previous.less.5 = tail(c(x[c((x[-n()] < 5), FALSE)]),1)) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(previous.less.5 = if_else(row_number() == n(), previous.less.5, NULL))
```

*or*

```r
df %>%
  arrange(id, time.var) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%   
  slice(1:(n()-1)) %>% 
  filter(x < 5) %>% 
  slice(n()) %>% 
  select(-time.var) %>% 
  right_join(df, ., by="id", suffix =c("",".y")) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(previous.less.5 = if_else(row_number() == n(), x.y, NULL)) %>%
  select(-x.y)
```

*giving:*

```
#> # A tibble: 20 x 4
#> # Groups:   id [3]
#>    id    time.var     x previous.less.5
#>    <fct>    <int> <int>           <int>
#>  1 A            3    10              NA
#>  2 A            4     8              NA
#>  3 A            4     6              NA
#>  4 A            5     2              NA
#>  5 A            5     8              NA
#>  6 A            5     7              NA
#>  7 A           11     6              NA
#>  8 A           13     3              NA
#>  9 A           15     2               3
#> 10 B            2     1              NA
#> 11 B            4     3              NA
#> 12 B            4     6              NA
#> 13 B            8     5              NA
#> 14 B            8     4              NA
#> 15 B           20     7               4
#> 16 C            1     2              NA
#> 17 C            2    10              NA
#> 18 C           10     6              NA
#> 19 C           13     2              NA
#> 20 C           18     5               2
```

## *Update:*

*If there's a group with no record less than 5 (or only last record less than 5) then following works:*

```r
df %>% 
  arrange(id, time.var) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(previous.less.5 = if_else(row_number() == n(), 
                                   max(tail(c( x[ c( x[-n()] < 5, FALSE) ] ), 1)), 
                                   NULL)) %>% 
  mutate(previous.less.5 = replace(previous.less.5, is.infinite(previous.less.5), NA))
```

***Data:***

```r
set.seed(42) # I am getting different data than what you've shown with this seed

df <- data.frame(
  id = sample(LETTERS[1:3], 20, replace = TRUE),
  time.var = sample(1:20, 20, replace = TRUE),
  x = sample(c(1:10), 20, replace = TRUE)
)

df <- df[order(df$id, df$time.var),]
```

Comment: A little simpler: `df %>%
  arrange(id, time.var) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(previous.less.5 = if_else(row_number() == n(), tail(sort(x[x < 5]), 1), NA_integer_))`.

Comment: @H1 One would argue over the concept of simplicity. In my eyes, `tail(c(x[c((x[-n()] < 5), FALSE)]),1)` by itself needs some thinking to be comprehended, so combining it by `if_else` would make it a bit more complicated. But your version is probably faster. Cheers.

Comment: In the case of a group without a value < 5, these methods return an error. Any error check or way around that condition or condition where `NA` may be the only other value present?

Answer (score 1):

We can reverse value of `x` by `id` get the first number which is less than 5 using `which`. The last `replace` is to assign `NA` to all the values in `previous.less.5` except the last one.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  #Data is already sorted by `id` and `time.var` but if your still need use
  #arrange(id, time.var) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(rev_x = c(NA, rev(x)[-1]), previous.less.5 = rev_x[which(rev_x < 5)[1]], 
         previous.less.5 = replace(previous.less.5, row_number() != n(), NA)) %>%
  select(-rev_x)

#   id    time.var     x previous.less.5
#   <fct>    <int> <int>           <int>
# 1 A            5     2              NA
# 2 A           14     8              NA
# 3 A           19     7              NA
# 4 A           20     1               2
# 5 B            1     1              NA
# 6 B            2     5              NA
# 7 B            9    10              NA
# 8 B           11    10              NA
# 9 B           13     6              NA
#10 B           15     4              NA
#11 B           19     3               4
#12 C            1     7              NA
#13 C            3     5              NA
#14 C            8     9              NA
#15 C            8     4              NA
#16 C           17     7              NA
#17 C           17     4              NA
#18 C           17     8              NA
#19 C           19     4              NA
#20 C           19    10               4
```

This should also handle the case and return `NA`'s if there is no value less than 5 in an `id`.